# Detect the last UITableViewCell of the current visible in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I would like to know if there is a way to detect if the current UITableViewCell is the last one in view then when the user pressed enter you will scroll the UITableView using this code

```
int cellHeight = 44;
[finishingTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(finishingTableView.contentOffset.x,finishingTableView.contentOffset.y + cellHeight) animated:YES];
```

I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells, each UItableViewCell has a UITextfield and I am programmatically selecting the UITableViewCell then making the cells textfield become first responder. I want to allow the user to hit enter all the way to the bottom of the UITableView but only start scrolling when the next UITableViewCell to select is out of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `indexPathsForVisibleRows` method of `UITableView`.

```
NSArray *visibleRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
NSIndexPath *lastRow = [visibleRows lastObject];
```

Then compare that to the indexPath you have for the cell you are dealing with.

Comment: In `visibleRows`, can we get all indexPath of TableView ??

Comment: @iPatel `visibleRows` contains the index paths of just the rows that are currently visible (fully or partially).

Comment: Oh,,, yes i just asking you because i have a bit confusion. thanks for clear me :) is it possible to get all indexPath of table ?

Comment: okay, this worked I have an if statment that tells me when I have reached the last cell however my setContentOffset is not working...

Comment: Use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` to put a specific row at the bottom (or top or middle) if that is your goal.